# Detect Changes Made to Input Field by Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I set my input field so that when user clicks on it, a [Bootstrap Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) is shown. I want to calculate something based on the date that is being entered in that input field through the datetimepicker.

I have thus defined my calculating function as:

```
$("#dob").on("input change bind", function (e) {
        //calculate age here.
    });
```

"dob" is the id for the input box. Datetimepicker correctly enters the datetime to the field. Code:

```
$('#dob').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            showClose: true
        });
```

Curiously, this bit of code works if I manually enter the date

```
$("#dob").change( function () {
        alert('DOB');
    });
```

But it is not called when the date is selected through Bootstrap Datetimepicker. What's causing the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#dob').change(function () { //OR $('#dob').on('change',function ()
    console.log($('#date-daily').val());
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('#dp3').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $('#dob').change();
});
$('#dob').change(function () {
    console.log($('#dob').val());
});
```

Comment: I forgot inform that I have tried this (just edited my question). This code works if I enter the date manually. It doesn't fire-up for dates selected through datetimepicker.

Comment: $("#dob").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    alert(this.value);
  }
});..use this

Comment: yah i have made jsfiddle fr u try it http://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/jwxvz/88/ @VivekanandPV

Comment: It appears you are using date-picker from jQueryUI. My question is about [Bootstrap datetimepicker.](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99452/discussion-between-debin-and-vivekanand-p-v).

Comment: $("#dob").on("dp.change", function(e) {
         alert();
      });